# Did any astronaut take a Bible into space?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, history, astronauts, space-station, astronaut-lifestyle

I am wondering if any astronauts took a copy of the Holy Bible into space.  I know the crew of Apollo 8 read part of Genesis 1 in space, but I am wondering if anyone took a full Holy Bible into space.

Comment: Of note: Buzz Aldrin took a small cross on a chain (the kind worn around one's neck) to the Moon. The cross is currently on display at the Cathedral Museum at the royal Wawel Castle, in Cracow, Poland.

Answer (score 7):

The astronauts' personal preference kit allowances were small enough that carrying a large format bible would be inconvenient. However, several [microfilm copies of the Bible were taken on Apollo missions](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/bible-microform-apollo-13/nasm_A19720199000).

Comment: The link appears to go somewhere other than what was desired.

Comment: Thanks, updated to something that might last another year or two.

Answer (score 4):

Ilan Ramon, an Israeli Air Force pilot took a very small Torah scroll (So complete first 5 books, Pentateuch in English/Greek I guess) on the Columbia mission that burned up on re-entry. (Columbia and crew burned up, I mean).

Comment: The bodies were burned, but remained in one part. 15 seconds later that the air escaped their cabin, they were unconscious. Ilan Ramon had hebrew first language, thus he understood the text in original version, which sounds archaic but understable for them (although he may have used an English on practical, or Greek on some traditional reason, the latter is in the case of a Jew unlikely). The small scroll may have survived the arrival (some worms for experiments survived), but if it survived, it likely wasn't ever found (as far I know, lesser as half of the Columbia's mass were ever found).

Comment: It was a Torah scroll, written in Hebrew in ink on parchment.  He could read it, as could anyone who can read modern Hebrew. Some of the words do not have modern usages. (Lots of animals and utensils that are not common).

Answer (score 0):

Later Apollo missions did leave a Bible on the Moon, in what amounts to a "ziploc bag." (They also left family photos in a bag. However, like the American Flags, all of these would have eventually been bleached white by the very strong sunlight, oh well.)
So, the answer to your question is, yes, but only on the later missions. NASA gave strong orders after Apollo 8 to downplay any religious talk. This is because they were sued by atheist O'Hair. I hope this helps.

Comment: Do you have any references to support your assertions?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: interesting: https://law.justia.com/cases/federal/district-courts/FSupp/312/434/1468840/ and https://www.episcopalnewsservice.org/2019/07/19/the-only-bible-on-the-moon-was-brought-there-by-an-episcopalian-on-behalf-of-his-parish/#:~:text=The%20Bible%20shown%20was%20left,Episcopal%20Church%20League%20City%2C%20Texas.

Comment: @blobbymcblobby yes, the O'Hair lawsuit part is true. But I don't think the bit about ziplocked Bibles littering the regolith is. Always willing to be convinced though.